# React Native Scrollable Tab View : tabBarUnderlineColor is not getting applied

Tags: react-native

Below is the code, the way I have used react-native-scrollable-tab-view:
Other than tabBarUnderlineColor , every style is getting applied!
I am refering "http://www.rntools.co/pkg/react-native-scrollable-tab-view" for the same

```
`<ScrollableTabView
    initialPage={0}
    renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
    tabBarUnderlineColor = '#ff6600'
    tabBarActiveTextColor='#ffffff'
    tabBarInactiveTextColor ='#747474'
    tabBarBackgroundColor = '#255a72'>
<View tabLabel='Activity1'></View>
<View tabLabel='Activity2'></View>
<View tabLabel='Activity3'></View>
</ScrollableTabView>`
```

Let me know, in case I have done any coding mistake.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: From package.json, I got this -> "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.5" @SahilDhir

Comment: you got the answer ... that great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
tabBarUnderlineStyle={{backgroundColor:'#fd8763',height:2,}}
```

[image: source code]

Answer (score 0):

`tabBarUnderlineColor` doesn't exist, you should use `tabBarUnderlineStyle`.

> tabBarUnderlineStyle (View.propTypes.style) - style of the default tab
>   bar's underline.

[source](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)